# show html code after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I want to create a web page show nothing contain button **Add new question**. When a user clicks on it, it adds two input type text every time. When it's clicked on, I save information entered in a database. How would I do this?

```
<input type="text" id="question"> <input type="text" id="answer">
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Which part of your requirement are you having trouble with? The whole "save in a database" thing is way too broad for this format. Regarding the HTML shown, that is valid in isolation, but if you want to add extra copies of it when a button is clicked that would result in invalid HTML because then you'd have duplicate IDs. The elements should have a `name` attribute and be in a `<form>` element so that they can be submitted.

Comment: i'm working on a web site now , i like to give the user the right to add a question and his answer then i save it in my db , ther is no solution to this problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function FNADDTEXTFIELD() {
        var PreviousFields=document.getElementById('txtField').innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('txtField').innerHTML =PreviousFields+ '<input type="text"><br>&ensp;<br><input type="text"><br>&ensp;<br>'
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="txtField">
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="FNADDTEXTFIELD()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for the PHP part, please ask a new question. However, here is the answer to "show html code after clicking on button".

```js
var i = 0;

jsForm = document.getElementById("js-form");

function addInputs() {
  i++;
  jsForm.innerHTML += '<div class="group-'+ i +'"><h3>Group '+ i + '</h3>Question: <input type="text" name="question' + i +'"><br>Answer: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="answer' + i + '"></div>';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addInputs()">Ask a new question</button>

<form id="js-form" action="process.php" method="POST">
</form>
```